# API's to SQL Azure

Tags: asp.net, api, azure, azure-sql-database

I have moved my SQL Server 2008 db with Stored Procedures onto SQL Azure.  Next I wanted to define an API endpoint to that server URL and with the right authorizations & inputs have the stored proc return JSON (or the like).

However research seems to indicate I need to route through another application/webserver/calling mechanism.  Frankly I'm hoping to concentrate on learning only db code (I.e. outsource the middle and frontend) so to some extent all I want to do at present is test . . . can anyone help me get a better understanding of the process???

Comment: I think trying to implement the API in the database would be a bad idea, possibly not even possible. I would take a look at WebAPI.

Comment: What do you mean by WebAPI?  It seems as if MS Azure has something called API management -- though I don't know what this is as yet.

Comment: I think you need to check [Premature Scalability and the Root of All Evil](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/premature-scalability-and-the-root-of-all-evil/) on why such an API is a *bad* idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Database (essentially SQL Server-as-a-Service) doesn't provide a data-access API built in. The only API's available for SQL Database service are system-level ones. That is, for provisioning and scaling. *Side note: Years ago, there was an experimental OData service offered for SQL Azure (the former name of SQL Database service), but that was terminated.*

You'd need to run a separate service to handle your API. How you do that is quite broad and subjective, and I'll avoid giving recommendations due to that, but... assuming you'll run your API in Azure, you have many places to run it, such as App Service (the most straightforward due to you not having to deal with *any* infrastructure), Cloud Services, and Virtual Machines. And then there's Azure API Management service (and since your question mentions authorization, this might be a good thing for you to look into). This is all documented at azure.com.